# How to handle a dynamic class differently based on expected return value

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dynamicobject

Which method of `DynamicObject` do I have to override in order to get a different behavior (in the dynamic class) based on the context in which the instance is used?

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
class DynamicTest : DynamicObject
{
    public DynamicTest(string xyz)
    {
        _xyz = xyz;
    }

    private string _xyz;

    //TODO: what do I need to implement to get required behaviour?
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic foo = new DynamicTest("test);

        if (foo)  // treat foo as boolean
        { // jump in here when _xyz of foo has a value
            System.Console.WriteLine(foo); //treat foo as string
        }
        else
        { // jump in here when _xyz of foo is null
            System.Console.WriteLine("No Value In Object");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why do you want to do this? Why don't you want to access field in some predicate?

Comment: In python a field with a value is considered true and with no value is false. I wanted a similar behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can help you

Example code:

```
class DynamicTest : DynamicObject
{
    public DynamicTest(string xyz)
    {
        _xyz = xyz;
    }

    private string _xyz;

    public static implicit operator bool(DynamicTest rhs)
    {
        return rhs._xyz != null;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(DynamicTest rhs)
    {
        return rhs._xyz;

    }

    //TODO: what to override to get required behaviour
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic foo = new DynamicTest("test");


        if (foo)  // treat foo as boolean
        { // jump in here when _xyz of foo has a value
            System.Console.WriteLine((string)foo); //treat foo as string   //Importat: (string)foo to go operatorstring 
        }
        else
        { // jump in here when _xyz of foo is null
            System.Console.WriteLine("No Value In Object");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why are you trying to do this and I will definitely **NOT** will recommend  doing this, but you can override TryConvert method on DynamicObject like:

```
class DynamicTest : DynamicObject
{
    public DynamicTest(string xyz)
    {
        _xyz = xyz;
    }
    private string _xyz;


    public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out Object result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("TryConvert was called");
        Console.WriteLine ("Is explicit: "+binder.Explicit);
        if(binder.Type == typeof(bool))
        {
            result = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if(binder.Type == typeof(string))
        {   
            result = _xyz;
            return true;
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _xyz;
    }
}
```

Now there are some issues: `ToString` is required for `Console.WriteLine`, it doesn't try to convert if no implicit convertions exist (because `WriteLine` is overloaded), so it calls `ToString`. Implicit and explicit conversions to `bool` pass, but if you use foo inside if - you will get `RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'DynamicTest' to 'bool'`.

**Examples:**

```
dynamic foo = new DynamicTest("test:");
bool boolFoo = foo; //passes, TryConvert is called with `binder.Explicit` == false
bool boolFoo1 = (bool)foo; //passes, TryConvert is called with `binder.Explicit` == true
if(foo) //throws RuntimeBinderException
```

Comment: I want this behavior because in many dynamic languages an object with a value is considered true and with no value is false. In c# without dynamic keyword you need to compare explicitly. What is fine but not in the api i am working on.